# Sending multiple Float64 messages to different topics

Tags: ros, gazebo, std-msgs, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to send multiple Float64 messages to different topics from the same Float64MultiArray, for example? Meaning, can I create a Float64MultiArray message and publish each element in the array to a different topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324570/sending-multiple-float64-messages-to-different-topics/) by [gerhmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/41972/gerhmi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-06-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-03**:
Why did you delete the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, that is not how ROS topics, publishers and subscribers work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0